# find the radius of convergence of the power series $\sum _1^{\infty} n^{-\sqrt n} z^n $

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

find the radius of convergence of the power series $\sum _1^{\infty} n^{-\sqrt n} z^n  $

here $a_n= n^{-\sqrt n}\\$

$ \frac{1}{R}=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} [ n^{-\sqrt n} ]^\frac{1}{n}$
for further i didnt get any one can help

Answer (score 3):

Hint: $$(n^{-\sqrt{n}})^{1/n}=n^{-1/\sqrt{n}}=e^{\frac{-\log n}{\sqrt{n}}}$$

Comment: @boon het..sorry i didt get your idea can you please explain

Comment: All you have to do is compute the limit on the right hand side. I gave you a hint on how to approach it.

Comment: yes but i dont understand how u wirte in exponential function

Comment: $a=e^{\log a}$ the apply the property  $\log(a^b)=b\log a$